# Can I close the main form from a child form?

Tags: c++builder

Is this code ok? Can the execution point correctly return after I call MainForm->Close()? Will the child form be properly closed?

```
void TChildForm::TestSomething()  
{
   if (SomethingFails)
      {
      MainForm->Close();  // I know Release() should be more appropriate than Close();
      return;
      }
   else EverythingIsFine_DoTheSettings;
}
```

Comment: It depends; If the `TfrmChild` instance is freed as a consequence of closing `MainForm` you might be in trouble.

Comment: Yes, the call site will be returned. Mainform.close calls application.terminate. Terminate posts a message to quit, so the child form will be properly closed/freed. FWIW, there's no difference between calling "close" and "release" for a **non**-main form that's to be freed, in this case "close" calls "release". All this for Delphi, don't know builder.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - What I ment with "release" is to show (in code) that I INTEND to exit "when possible", as opposite to "exit right now" (Terminate or ExitProcess). Even if it is doing the same, Release has a different "flavor" when you see it/read it in a piece of code :)   I will accept your comment is you post is as answer. Many thanks.

Comment: That's Ok, that part was not really related with your code since you're closing the *main* form. Better for someone who know builder to answer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - I know, I know it was not critic :) :) :)

Comment: Out of curiosity: for how long I can keep abusing (read it as "using") the main form, AFTER I called Close on it? I guess until somewhere in the code, someone calls  Application->ProcessMessages (I know that ProcessMessages is evil! I try to avoid it). Then the application has a chance to see the close message posted in the loop and will actually free the main form. Accessing it after that point will result in some AV. (my guess).

Comment: As long as the queue is emptied. All sent/posted messages will be processed. Although not officially documented, WM_QUIT has lower priority then posted messages ([link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=33453)). Application.ProcessMessages will empty the queue.

Comment: @Rigel "*Out of curiosity: for how long I can keep abusing (read it as "using") the main form, AFTER I called Close on it?*" - until `Application->Terminated` becomes true once the `WM_QUIT` message has actually been processed. `Application->Run()` will exit when it sees `Terminated=true`. But even then, the `MainForm` is not actually freed until the `TApplication` object is destroyed, which is not until after the app's `WinMain()` has exited. You are basically OK as long as `WinMain()` is still running, but you shouldn't be doing anything after then, except maybe cleanup in global objects.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz "*All this for Delphi, don't know builder*" - everything behaves the same in C++Builder, too.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - Thanks a lot for the link! I will post it one more time. IT IS IMPORTANT that all people with similar questions will read the article!!  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=33453